# Issue retrieving longitude/latitude using Google Static Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-asynctask, google-maps-static-api

I am running into an issue where I need to get the Longitude / Latitude from an address that is passed into an AsyncTask that retrieves a Google Static Map.

This AsyncTask can take a set of coordinates and create a map, and it can also take an address that is retrieved using Google Places API.

The issue I am having is that I don't know how I can retrieve the coordinates of the address that is passed in. Does anyone know a way that I can get the Long/Lat? The only way I have figured out how to do it is by using another AsyncTask. I would rather not make 2 requests though.

**CREATE STATIC MAP**
    class CreateStaticMapAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    private static final String STATIC_MAPS_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap";
    private static final String STATIC_MAPS_API_SIZE = "300x300";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        addTask(); // adds one to task count.
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        locationString = params[0];
        Log.e("LOCATION STRING", locationString);
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(STATIC_MAPS_API_BASE);
        try {
            sb.append("?center=").append(
                    URLEncoder.encode(locationString, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        sb.append("&size=" + STATIC_MAPS_API_SIZE);
        sb.append("&key=" + API_KEY);
        String url = new String(sb.toString());
        Log.e("URL", sb.toString());

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = httpclient.execute(request).getEntity().getContent();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmp;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) {
        super.onPostExecute(bmp);
        if (bmp != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            data = stream.toByteArray();
            removeTask();
            // allTasksComplete();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`Geocoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class.

> A class for handling geocoding and reverse geocoding. Geocoding is the
>   process of transforming a street address or other description of a
>   location into a (latitude, longitude) coordinate.

If you go over [the example](http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html), you will see that `Geocoder` is used in a background thread. Since you already have an `AsyncTask`, you can add the code to `doInBackground()` itself. The example will need to be modified because you need a latitude and longitude from address and not the other way around.

You will need the `getFromLocationName()` method:

> Returns an array of Addresses that are known to describe the named
>   location, which may be a place name such as "Dalvik, Iceland", an
>   address such as "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA", an
>   airport code such as "SFO", etc.. The returned addresses will be
>   localized for the locale provided to this class's constructor.

Then from the `Address` object, you can get the latitude and longitude.